# Unable to login to admin site in localhost

Tags: django, django-admin, localhost

I can't login to the admin site on localhost.

I try with firefox, IE.

I try using the 127.0.0.1:8000 address. Also, I set the `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` to `localhost`, `localhost:8000`

I change the host file to:

```
127.0.0.1       test.com
```

and set:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'test.com'
```

I can login in production (only after the `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` configuration).

I'm using django rev 1.0.1. I can't upgrade to last trunk. The best, is move to 1.0.2.

**Update**: I try adding to the host file my public domain, and not works (ie: `127.0.0.1 www.mysite.com`).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have localhost pointing to 127.0.0.1 in your /etc/hosts, set your SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN to 'localhost' (nb: port numbers are NOT part of the hostname) and start the dev server with the appropriate domain and port, ie:

```
./manage.py runserver localhost:8000
```

FWIW, I never had to mess with SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN in any Django version since the 0.96 days.